# Prepending ENVVARs in command line of make target doesn't work consistently on Windows

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile with a target that prepends an environment variable to the shell call (with the usual bash syntax). This is the gist of it:

```
mytest:
    ANSWER=42 echo Hello!
```

(the real deal is a programme that does something with the ENV `ANSWER`, but that's irrelevant here)

This works as expected in a linux/bash environment. In `windows/cmd.exe` environments it works to my surprise in some machines, but fails in others with this error:

```
> make mytest
MYVAR=42 echo Hello!
'MYVAR' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [Makefile:332: mytest] Error 1
```

Which is what I'd normally expect, since `ENVVAR=<value> <command>` isn't valid syntax in the windows shell. Apparently Make does some magic that I don't understand.

If I pre-export the ENV this way, it works as expected:

```
mytest: export ANSWER:=42
mytest:
    echo Hello!
```

But since it works on some windows environments, I'd like to know why and maybe adapt those instead of changing a lot of Makefiles.

All of the environments are using GNU Make version `4.3`.

Comment: How did you install Make on Windows? There's `mingw32-make` which uses CMD (which I'd expect to fail on this syntax), and then there are cygwin-based `make` ports (like the one from MSYS2) which use `sh`, and which should work exactly like on Linux.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat in my very case, I installed it via scoop. And its behaviour is to use `sh.exe` if in path, `cmd.exe` otherwise, without reporting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running on Windows is complicated because GNU make can be built in different ways there.  Sometimes it is built to use Windows `cmd.exe` as its shell.  Sometimes it's built to use an installation of `sh.exe` as its shell (note, GNU make never comes with a shell: the shell is a separate facility provided on the system).  And sometimes it's built to use `sh.exe` if it can find one, else use `cmd.exe`.

If you're seeing different behaviors on different systems, then the way make was built is different between those systems, and/or different systems have different extra software installed so that some have `sh.exe` and some don't.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was driving me crazy. Apparently I have a make version that uses `sh.exe` if available, and otherwise falls silently back to `cmd.exe`. Make is no good for mental health.

Comment: You can set the `SHELL` makefile variable to a specific value, then if it's not found make will fail.  This ensures you're always either using the same shell, or your build fails immediately.

Comment: Hi @MadScientist, unfortunately that seems not to be the case. I tried and no error was raised. Which is consistent with the docs:  `However, if none of these is found, the value of SHELL will not be changed, and thus the line that sets it will be effectively ignored` (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html)

Comment: Oh.  Bummer.  Sorry for the misleading comment.  As mentioned I don't do Windows :)

Comment: It doesn't matter, you helped a ton :)